# Dropdown not working with selenium for this site

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I tried using the below code to use the dropdown from the foodpanda site and choose the city name but it's not working for me.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.foodpanda.in/restaurants/city/pune?gclid=CIbFi5iEvdMCFdeFaAodujsK5w");
        Thread.sleep(5000);


        WebElement drp =driver.findElement(By.id("cityId"));
        Select drp2 = new Select(drp);
        drp2.selectByVisibleText("Bangalore");
```

It gives out the error-
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Comment: Why is it not working?

Comment: It says - ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Comment: why don't you try `ExplicitWait`?

Answer (score 1):

That `<select>` element has  the CSS `display: none;`. Its just a place holder.
I think the site uses some fancy `<span>`s to get the awesome look of the drop down. Can you please check that?

Answer (score 0):

So I was trying to figure out how the dropdown works & here's what I found. The `select` is just a placeholder, it has no role on the webpage. The dropdown is populated using a javascript call when the `input` box (see below) is clicked.

[image]

Once you click inside the `input` box, some DOM elements are added which contain `<p>` tag with city names, which when clicked, selects the target city you want to select.

Based on my observation, a `span` with class name `tt-suggestions` is visible when the input element is clicked. This `span` has a `div` within it which has all the `p` elements within it. You should aim to click the corresponding `p` element which has the text of your desired city name.

Here's a working code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control twitter-typeahead tt-input']")
).click(); // this will click inside the input element
WebElement drp = (WebElement) wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                 By.xpath("//span[@class='tt-suggestions']"))); // this is the span element which gets populated
System.out.println(drp.getAttribute("innerHTML")); // just in case you want to see the above span's HTML code
drp.findElement(By.xpath("//div/p[text()[contains(.,'Bangalore')]]")).click(); // This will select Bangalore from the Dropdown
```

Comment: HI I am getting this error after adding wait- Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: cityId

Comment: @Jayesh Doolani, No, the element is permanently invisible, So selenium click is not possible in this place(Since selectByVisibleText internally does the click operation).

Comment: @SladeWilsonXXX I have modified my answer. Try this